# Why are 2 Shevatim missing a Vav

Tags: tanach, shevatim-12-tribes, ki-tavo, deuteronomy

In [Devarim 27:12-13](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.27.13?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)

> אֵ֠לֶּה יַֽעַמְד֞וּ לְבָרֵ֤ךְ אֶת־הָעָם֙ עַל־הַ֣ר גְּרִזִ֔ים בְּעׇבְרְכֶ֖ם אֶת־הַיַּרְדֵּ֑ן שִׁמְעוֹן֙ וְלֵוִ֣י וִֽיהוּדָ֔ה וְיִשָּׂשכָ֖ר וְיוֹסֵ֥ף וּבִנְיָמִֽן׃
> וְאֵ֛לֶּה יַֽעַמְד֥וּ עַל־הַקְּלָלָ֖ה בְּהַ֣ר עֵיבָ֑ל רְאוּבֵן֙ גָּ֣ד וְאָשֵׁ֔ר וּזְבוּלֻ֖ן דָּ֥ן וְנַפְתָּלִֽי

> After you have crossed the Jordan, the following shall stand on Mount Gerizim when the blessing for the people is spoken: Simeon, Levi, Judah, Issachar, Joseph, and Benjamin.
> And for the curse, the following shall stand on Mount Ebal: Reuben, Gad, Asher, Zebulun, Dan, and Naphtali.

Gad and Dan are mentioned without a "vav" before their name while the others all have (except obviously the first in each passuk) . Any reason given for that?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28875/4940

Comment: (1) As a native born Israeli, I was taught that only the last item in a list should get a "vav". So, to me, Levi and Yosef being mentioned with a "vav" _would_ seem superfluous. (2) For what it's worth, [Iben Ezra on Shemot 1:4, s.v. "Dan"](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.1.4?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Ibn_Ezra_on_Exodus.1.4.1&lang2=bi) says (in translation): "_Names are connected to each other in Scripture in six different ways. All of these styles are correct_". Then, it goes on to enumerate the different ways with examples.